# How to make the hero section always fill browser window?

Tags: jquery, css, fullscreen, viewport

I was wondering how I can fill a hero image to the browser viewport. So that the height of the hero section is always the height of the viewport.

I came up with the following piece of code, but it isn't working:

```
function resizer() {
  var fulls = $('#hero');
  console.log(fulls);
  var win = $(window);

  resize.on(function() {
    fulls.height(win.height());
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#hero').height($(window).height());
}).resize();
```

Comment: It's working. Great. One thing. Now the user must be resize the window to effect the code. When I remove the 'resize()' function. It also works. But how should I make the code so it will do both functions?@Felix

Answer (score 4):

Simply, use the viewport width and height:

```
fulls.style.height = "100vh"; //which means 100% of the viewport height, same works for width
```

It will be a good idea to set the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code here http://jsfiddle.net/F7AN5/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="hero">
      <img src="http://www.thememorist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/superhero-blank1.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
img{
    display:block;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var resizeHero = function()
    {
      var hero = $("#hero"), window1 = $(window);
        hero.css({
            "width": window1.width(),
            "height": window1.height()
        });

        if(window1.width() < window1.height())
        {
             hero.find("img").css({
            "width": window1.width(),
            "height": "auto"
            });        
        }
        else
        {
             hero.find("img").css({
             "height": window1.height(),
             "width": "auto"
            });            
        }
    };

    resizeHero();

    $(window).resize(function(){
      resizeHero();    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS-free solution.
Haven't tested, but should work in theory.

Assuming the markup is...

```
<div id="hero">
      <img src="http://www.thememorist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/superhero-blank1.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Then it could use the `object-fit` style, which only requires the parent to have a height...

```
#hero {height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
#hero img { object-fit: cover; }
```

The object fit size works like newer background-image sizes: cover | contain | fit | 100% | etc

[More about object-fit css.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)